# relativo + oggetto diretto

Tags: grammar, word-usage, regional, pronouns

Da un articolo su *Irpinia Report*:

> Ognuno ha portato una pietanza, **che l’ha divisa** con gli altri.

- di che tipo di fenomeno linguistico si tratta?
- si può classificare come un fenomeno linguistico di stampo regionale/meridionale?

Answer (score 8):

A me sembra più un refuso che un fenomeno linguistico di qualche tipo. Refusi simili possono derivare da una variazione fatta ad una frase, ma non portata a termine. P.es., potrebbe essere che la frase fosse, ad un certo punto,

> Ognuno ha portato una pietanza, **e l'ha divisa** con gli altri.

e che l'intenzione fosse di farla diventare

> Ognuno ha portato una pietanza, **che ha diviso** con gli altri.

Oppure può darsi che la frase iniziale fosse quest'ultima. La frase iniziale potrebbe eventualmente avere avuto vita solo nella testa dello scrivente, che ha cambiato idea "frase facendo".

Ad ogni modo, il risultato è una sorta di raddoppio del pronome che sta per *pietanza* (*che* e *la*). Come evidenziato da @DaG, è possibile sentire raddoppi simili nella lingua parlata («un posto che ci vado spesso», «un problema che gli abbiamo dedicato molta attenzione»), ma si tratta di lingua parlata **male**, di cui non conosco la distribuzione regionale. Dubito però che l'autore di un articolo di giornale possa arrivare coscientemente a tanto.

Comment: Nel parlato incontro spesso fenomeni analoghi («un posto che ci vado spesso», «un problema che gli abbiamo dedicato molta attenzione»), ma nello scritto è (per ora?) impensabile.

Comment: @DaG, hai ragione, quasi quasi cancello la mia risposta, perché gli esempi che porti sono effettivamente simili al caso in esame

Comment: No, Walter, la tua analisi è buonissima, anche per chiarire a chi studia italiano le idee sulle forme corrette. Aggiungevo solo un appunto su un uso del parlato, che non è detto sia alla base della frase citata.